# Your own Bookmarklet in a blog

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting, bookmark

Does anyone know how to publish your own bookmarklet in a blog like wordpress.com or blogger.com? All of them seem to format the bookmarklet removing the javascript or messing it up.

E.g., pasting this in wordpress blog:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){$.hide()});" title="Run"></a>
```

results in

```
<a href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove()}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c)}})(window,document,"1.3.2",function($,L){$.hide()});">Run jQuery Code</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a clickable link on http://jsfiddle.net/ and link to it.

Comment: Ended up using this approach. Marking it as answer as this is closest. Here's the blog post: http://hkpanda.posterous.com/web-20-pop-up-blocker

Answer (score 1):

WordPress.com [does not allow to post JavaScript](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/#javascript).

You should follow instruction on [posting source code](http://en.support.wordpress.com/code/posting-source-code/) or put it on externals snippets service (such as [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) for example) and link to it.

Unfortunately neither will do as active clickable bookmarklet link.

Answer (score 0):

Most visual editors will attempt to format your code. If wrapping it in the `<code> </code>` tags doesn't work, attempt this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inline-javascript/

Comment: WP.com question, no plugins. :)